# Key length error logging into store on GREG 5.0 using SSO and custom Cert

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

We have been implementing GREG5.0 and using default configurations everything works fine.  Once we replace the default localhost certificate in the wso2cabon.jks keystore with our own we receive "java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 128" when we log into Store or Publisher using SSO.

We have removed the default keypair from wso2carbon.jks and added our own certificate.  The password for our keystore and certificate are the same.  We have updated all the configuration files per the wso2 carbon 4.4 documentation.  We have updated JavaHome with local_policy.jar and us_export_policy.jar in order to allow for the longer key length.

The administrator console works great with no issues.  If we change the login method of store or publisher to "basic" then it works fine.  When we have the login method set to "SSO" we end up sitting on a blank page at this location https://servername/store/acs.  We have the same result in the browser if we are running as a windows server or in console mode but, if we are running as a windows service then we have no error and no indication of what happened.  If we are running in console mode then I get the error mentioned above spit out in the console.

I also noticed this behavior on Identity Server 5.0 when accessing dashboard.

We are running on windows.

Is there another location in WSO2 that I need to update to accomodate an increased key length?

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location I missed updating was the IdentityAlias in repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/config/store.json repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/config/publisher.json.  Once I updated that value to match the alias of the keypair I was using in wso2carbon.jks that appeared as though it solved the keylength error and created another problem.

So now it was giving me a NullPointerException.  I had provided the alias of our keypair but that was not the same as the alias for our certificate exported from our keypair that we loaded in client-truststore.jks.  So I decided to set both alias' so they would match.  With that change I was finally able to successfully able to access the store and publisher.

After some further testing it did not care what my keypair alias was as long as the value in IdentityAlias matched the alias of my certificate loaded in client-truststore.jks.

Hope this helps someone.
Joe